# Unsupported file format error occurs when I'm using .png in pygame

Tags: python, pygame

I am making a game in pygame and I have this unusual error that hasn't happened before. I am trying to animate my player and in the code I print the data that I'm getting. Whenever I use the path to the run animation, it runs perfectly. But when I try with the idle animations it returns this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/dhruv/Documents/Games/2D Platformer Logic/scripts/support.py", line 15, in <module>
    print(import_folder('../graphics/character/idle'))
  File "/Users/dhruv/Documents/Games/2D Platformer Logic/scripts/support.py", line 11, in import_folder
    img_surf = pygame.image.load(full_path)
pygame.error: Unsupported image format
```

I have checked the files, they are all .png files. So why am I getting this error? Here is my code btw.

```
import pygame
from os import walk

def import_folder(path):
    surface_list = []

    for _, __, img_files in walk(path):
        real_imgs = sorted(img_files)
        for image in real_imgs:
            full_path = path + '/' + image
            img_surf = pygame.image.load(full_path)
            surface_list.append(img_surf)
    return surface_list

print(import_folder('../graphics/character/idle'))
```

Comment: Print `full_path` before the `image.load()` call, so you can see what actual filename it fails on.

Comment: after doing that I found an extra file called .DS_Store but when I look in the folder, the file isn't there. Any idea what to do?

Comment: It "isn't there" because filenames that begin with a period are not displayed by the `ls` command by default.

Comment: In the for loop, check if the filename starts with a period, and if so, skip that filename and proceed to the next one.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a `try`/ `except` loop to trap and ignore the loading errors:

```
import pygame
from os import walk

def import_folder(path):
    surface_list = []

    for _, __, img_files in walk(path):
        real_imgs = sorted(img_files)
        for image in real_imgs:
            try:
                full_path = path + '/' + image
                img_surf = pygame.image.load(full_path)
                surface_list.append(img_surf)
            except pygame.error:
                print(f"Unable to load image {full_path}")
    return surface_list

print(import_folder('../graphics/character/idle'))
```

Or you could use a pattern based search (known as a [glob](https://docs.python.org/3/library/glob.html)). Here's an example using [Pathlib](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html), which is much nicer that `os.walk()` and friends:

```
from pathlib import Path

def import_folder(path):
    surface_list = []
    img_files = Path(path).glob("*.png")
    for img_file in img_files:
        img_surf = pygame.image.load(img_file)
        surface_list.append(img_surf)
    return surface_list
```